# Nx react application is not generating optimized bundle for production build

Tags: webpack-5, nrwl-nx, webpack-module-federation

My microfrontend react application is created using Nx Tool. It has been created using Nrwl react executor and the present configuration is untouched & is the default configuration provided by Nx.

When I build the application in production mode, the bundle generated is not minimized & not performance optimized. In project.json, flags were set for optimized code, but they were not being honoured.

In project.json, if I replace the   value of *targets > build > options > "webpackConfig"* from **custom webpack path** to **"@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack"**, it honors the optimization flags and works as expected, but it doesnt generate remoteEntry.js file which is required by the host  app to render the micro frontend app.

I also tried customizing the webpack based on this [official documentation](https://nx.dev/recipes/other/customize-webpack#module-federation), but the code returns error

**Changes in webpack i tried with:**

```
const withModuleFederation = require('@nrwl/react/module-federation');
const moduleFederationConfig = require('./module-federation.config');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;

/* ========1 Orginal Code snippet================= */
//Creates remoteEntry.js file, but not uglified code
 module.exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...moduleFederationConfig,
}); 

/* =======2 ================== */
```

//Returns error:  NX   customWebpack is not a function
/* module.exports = {

```
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      ...moduleFederationConfig,
    }),
  ],
}; */
```

**Steps to replicate:**

1. Code exists here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-azwv9t or get from GIT: https://github.com/kalingaCoder/react_MF
2. Do npm install
3. Do npm run build-cart
4. check bundle output here: dist\apps\cart ( files should be minimized, but that is not happening)

**Files to check:**

apps\cart\project.json    : *targets > build > configurations > production*
apps\cart\webpack.config.js
apps\host\module-federation.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed now, Earlier I was using @nrwl version 14, after migrating to latest, the issue is resolved.

Ran the below command to upgrade
nx migrate latest # same as nx migrate @nrwl/workspace@latest